# Discord.py bot doesn't start the build when runned on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

A few days ago, my discord BOT was running perfectly, but then, yesterday, when i wanted to push my changes to heroku, and started the bot from "Resources" my bot did not start the build, it's not active on discord and the logs keep freezing at State changed from starting to up` . But then, when i want to stop it, appears:

```
2020-10-25T18:25:09.969434+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-10-25T18:25:10.673640+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-10-25T18:25:10.746063+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Everytime when i start the BOT: \

```
2020-10-25T18:24:52.250959+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command python config.py
2020-10-25T18:24:52.831038+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

And then freezes at this, without starting the build.

Last days it was running good, and then, this happend, can someone help me?

BUILD LOG:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py (from -r /tmp/build_3e455f20_/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Cloning https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py to /tmp/pip-req-build-zrpy69ls
         Running command git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py /tmp/pip-req-build-zrpy69ls
       Building wheels for collected packages: discord.py
         Building wheel for discord.py (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for discord.py (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for discord.py: filename=discord.py-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl size=700651 sha256=c46db07cd3766eaa701ac68415028eacd4536fe1a7f968c4f41afa57eaca0742
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-lxidpdt2/wheels/5a/bd/bc/77c6c9d1b89e2f5684c3e1b7fa3df40131bec5af81623f33a8
       Successfully built discord.py
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> worker
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 80.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v35
       https://pheonix-bot.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: The build is only run once after a code change. Starting the bot does not trigger the build. Since you committed a change you should post the entire build.log. Go to your Heroku App. Select "Overview". On the right side you find "latest activity", there you can select "View build log"

Comment: i added the log in the post

Comment: build looks fine. It's probably your python code.